# Is it possible to find out if the uninstaller wants a reboot?

Tags: inno-setup

Uninstallation of my program sometimes requires a reboot of the computer, depending if some *.dll files are in use by Windows Explorer or not.

Now I want to automatically uninstall an older version of my program if a newer version is installed. I used

```
MyUninstallerName := OldInstallationDirectory + 'unins000.exe';

function UninstallPreviousVersion : Boolean;
var
  ResultCode : Integer;
begin
  Result := Exec(MyUninstallerName, '/silent', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

The uninstallation of the older version is called as first step of the installation of a newer version after the 'Ready to install' page:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then 
    UninstallPreviousVersion;
end;
```

This works fine if a reboot of the computer is not necessary. However, if the computer has to be rebooted, then the uninstaller displays
a window asking 'Do you want to reboot the computer?' after the old version has been uninstalled, while at the same time the installation of the new version continues. This is a highly confusing user experience.

I solved this tentatively by preventing the restart by the uninstaller, and I restart each time the previous version was uninstalled.

```
function UninstallPreviousVersion : Boolean;
var
  ResultCode : Integer;
begin
  PreviousVersionWasUninstalled := True;
  Result := Exec(MyUninstallerName, '/silent /norestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := PreviousVersionWasUnInstalled;
end;
```

While this is better (the question 'Do you want to reboot the computer?' appears at the very end of the uninstallation/installation process), it is still not perfect, however. Now each time an uninstallation is performed this results in a reboot, while the reboot is actually only necessary
sometimes and sometimes not.

Is it possible to find out (for example from the ResultCode) if the uninstaller wants a reboot?

Comment: I do not think that the uninstaller returns a specific exit code when restart is needed. Cannot you just test for existence of the files that need to be removed (or maybe for the existence of the uninstaller binary?).

Comment: Yes, I can test for existence of the files. However, this is not very elegant: The uninstaller already knows that he could not remove these files, and it would be easier if he would share his knowledge.

Comment: "Is it possible to find out (for example from the ResultCode) if the uninstaller wants a reboot?" No. See [Uninstaller Exit Codes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstexitcodes) in the help: "Programs checking the exit code to detect failure should not check for a specific non-zero value; any non-zero exit code indicates that the uninstaller was not run to completion."